# Calling a function with Attribute

Tags: c#, methods, attributes

I have a function that uses an instance of stopwatch to measure the time of method by starting and stopping. 
Can I somehow define that function inside an attribute and just decorate any given method with that attribute to measure time of that method ? 
That would reduce the LOC. 
I don't want to use any third party library.

```
public class AppTrace:BaseModel<AppTrace>
   {
    [DataMember]
    public string Comment;
    [DataMember]
    public string MethodName;
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime StartTimeStamp;
    [DataMember]
    public int Duration;
    [DataMember]
    public int UserObjectId;
    [DataMember]
    public string MachineName;
    [DataMember]
    public int ToolId;
    private System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stpWatch;


    public AppTrace(string comment,string methodName,int userObjectId   ,string machineName = "",int? toolId=null)
    {
        MethodName = methodName;
        UserObjectId = userObjectId;
        StartTimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Comment = comment;
        MachineName = machineName;

        stpWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        stpWatch.Start();
    }

    public AppTrace()
    {
    }

    public void CloseTrace()
    {
        this.stpWatch.Stop();
        Duration=Convert.ToInt32( this.stpWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

}
```

if not attribute, can I do this with the help of delegates?

Comment: Check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966730/can-i-use-the-decorator-pattern-to-wrap-a-method-body), I think it answers your question

Comment: No, it's not possible. 
You have to write some method invoker utility, which will actually start and stop `StopWatch` (for example `Invoke.Measure(() => {/*do some stuff*/})`) or use some AOP framework instead(`PostSharp`, for example, which uses IL rewriting at compile time).

Comment: i am starting and stopping the stopwatch inside that predefined function.

Comment: I have a function which starts stopwatch and one function which stops it. now, to measure the time of any given methods, I have to call these two functions before and after. So, to reduce loc, can I use an attribute?

Comment: Attribute can just contain meta information, it cannot perform any actions. And even if you will define such an attribute, some upper-level code have to find it with reflection and use in appropriate way. 
It's simpler to use static utility and lambdas instead.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comments, it's not possible generally. You may use some AOP framework, which handles such things rather successfull. Or write some invocation utility.

In the simplest case your utility can look like this:

```
public static class Invoke 
{
    public static TimeSpan Measure(Action action)
    {
        if (action == null)
        { 
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        action();
        stopWatch.Stop();

        return stopWatch.Elapsed;
    }  
}
```

Then you will be able to measure method invocation time. For example, class `Foo` will be used as measurement target.

```
// don't use such naming in production code
public class Foo
{
    public void DoWork1()
    {
        // imitating hard computations
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    }

    public void DoWork2(int param1) 
    {
        // imitating hard computations
        Thread.Sleep(param1);
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();

        // signature of foo.DoWork1 is suitable for Invoke.Measure, 
        //so you can use it as MethodGroup
        var time1 = Invoke.Measure(foo.DoWork1);
        Console.WriteLine("Time for 'DoWork1' is {0}s", time1.TotalSeconds);

        // signature of foo.DoWork2 is not suitable for Invoke.Measure,   
        // so you have to call it inside additional lambda 
        var time2 = Invoke.Measure(() => foo.DoWork2(42));
        Console.WriteLine("Time for 'DoWork2' is {0}s", time2.TotalSeconds);
    }
}
```

It will be harder for methods, which return some values, but could also be implemented. Adding helper class `Timed<T>` which will contain return value as well as operation duration.

```
public class Timed<T>
{
    public readonly TimeSpan Duration;
    public readonly T Result;

    // making constructor private to force static factories usage
    private Timed(T result, TimeSpan duration) 
    {
        Result = result;
        Duration = duration;
    }

    // static factory method instead of constructor, for generic parameter 
    // type inference 
    public static Timed<T> Create(T result, TimeSpan duration) 
    {
        return new Timed<T>(result, duration);
    }
}
```

Then overload for `Invoke.Measure` will be required.

```
public static class Invoke 
{
    // Func<T> instead of Action
    public static Timed<T> Measure(Func<T> func)
    {
        if (func== null)
        { 
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var result = func();
        stopWatch.Stop();

        return Timed.Create(result, stopWatch.Elapsed);
    }  
}
```

By the way `F# REPL` has `#time` directive to measure invocation time. And you could call any `.NET` code from `F#`. It's integrated into Visual Studio or could be called from command line (`fsi.exe`). I don't know your actual goal, so it could be suitable.

Comment: Can't I pass the method name to the Attribute property and inside that attribute write the function which starts and stops. Let me add those functions.

Comment: Can I use delegates to reduce LOC?

Comment: Of course, you could write a method inside attribute, which will measure function timing with use of stopwatch. But that function won't be invoked automagically. So you still have to write some code, which will invoke your attribute method. It's not not worth the trouble, I suppose.

You can use delegates for "logic" code and static helper, which will actually do all the dirty work of time measurement for you. That's the thing I wrote in my answer. 

Nothing to add here.