# Are there decorators in java or c# like python functools decorators i.e. @wraps

Tags: java, c#, python-decorators

Decorators are a significant part of Python. In simple words: they are functions which modify the functionality of another function. They help to make our code shorter.

For example:

```
def greet(name):
   def get_message():
       return "Hello "

result = get_message()+name
return result

print greet("John")

# Outputs: Hello John
```

We can do the work more shorter and easy in the code above with python function decorators:

```
 @greet
 def get_message():
     return "Hello"
```

I think decorators are very useful. Is there something like that in java or c#. I know @override etc. but I couldn't find python-like decorators.

Comment: If you cared to explain what these decorators do, maybe we can answer without looking up on the internet what you meant.

Comment: If you are in a C# or Java area, it may be worthwhile linking to or describing what you mean by decorators so we know what you are talking about.

Comment: There are many different things, depending on what your actual goal for those decorators is. For some there might be a 1to1-replacement (e.g. @Override in Java or `override`-keyword in C#), for others you´d have to use `Attribute` or similar. So on what is your *specific* problem?

Comment: The question as such is not as bad as the votes imply. But, as you can see, nobody here knew anything about python decorators. So a little example or at least an aim beyond it being 'useful' would have helped. But not responding to all comments really kills it.  - You will want to study delegates, as this is the c# equivalent to 'function as variable'. (Note that the `@` is just syntatic sugar.)

Comment: Glad you improved your question. Now if it were as simple to get rid of all those downvotes..

Comment: For C# it could be a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966730/can-i-use-the-decorator-pattern-to-wrap-a-method-body)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an equivalent to decorators in Java.

As I understand it, decorators in Python are essentially syntactic sugar for method transformations.  For example (from [PEP 318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/)):

```
def foo(cls):
    pass

foo = synchronized(lock)(foo)
foo = classmethod(foo)
```

becomes this:

```
@classmethod
@synchronized(lock)
def foo(cls):
    pass
```

That kind of thing won't work in Java because Java methods are not first class objects, and the binding between a Java method and a method name is not mutable.

You might be able to do some things that you can do with Python decorators using annotation-driven code Java source code or bytecode rewriting, etcetera.  However decorators implemented that way should be considered part of the Java language.  (Just like Lombok-ified Java isn't real Java.)