# How to prevent method invoking when Attribute return false?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, aop

I have a software that requires a license key validation on some methods. It a little bit uncomfortable to write a general wrapper for this purpose, so I want to write something like this:

```
    [EnsureThat(LicenseKeyAdded = true)]
    public static void SomeSeriousMethod()
    {
       // My very confidential code
    }
```

LicenseKeyAdded is a property inside the class, that was set somewhere outside. And the main idea is not to execute this method when the attribute's result is false (display alert message instead)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use the decorator pattern to wrap a method body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966730/can-i-use-the-decorator-pattern-to-wrap-a-method-body) It looks like this is not possible.