# MS Tests DataTestMethod Timeout for a single test

Tags: c#, automated-tests, timeout, mstest, data-driven-tests

I use MSTest (2.1.2) and I have a data-driven test.

```
[DataTestMethod]
[ExpenseTypesData]
[Timeout(600000)]
public void ManualExpenseReportTest(string category)
{
}
```

Is it possible to set a timeout for a single data row test and not all data rows?

This test will fail on timeout no matter if I have 2 or 200 rows. Needless to say, I do not know how many tests are going to be executed so changing a number is not an option. As well as that, I don't want one stuck test to hold other data rows.

Answer (score 1):

There is ongoing discussion about this on github: https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/issues/728 as users expectation is that `TimeoutAttribute` will be applied per `DataRow`. Unfortunately last answer is from August 2020, so there is not much hope in fixing that.

If you really need it and you want to build your own solution, you can wrap your test in asynchronous `Task` and wait whatever timeout you need per row. Something like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass1
{
    private int Timeout => 500;

    [DataTestMethod]
    [DataRow(100)]
    [DataRow(1000)]
    [DataRow(250)]
    [DataRow(1500)]
    [DataRow(100)]
    public void Test1(int delay)
    {
        Task task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(delay); // Your test goes here

            Assert.IsTrue(true); // Your asserts go here
        });

        if (!task.Wait(Timeout))
            Assert.Fail("Test failed with timeout");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! As I found out from this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966730/can-i-use-the-decorator-pattern-to-wrap-a-method-body), using your approach with PostSharp decorators will allow creating your own Timeout decorator. It's pity Microsoft overlooked data-driven test timeouts.